# what does "content" : mean in swagger/openapi "responses":

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-codegen

Using Swagger/OpenAPI (and subsequently swagger-codegen) I haven't been able to find what the difference *should* be between

This, taken direclty from https://swagger.io/specification/#responsesObject
(first example, json format)

```
"responses" : {
  "200": {
    "description": "a pet to be returned",
    "content": {
      "application/json": {
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Pet"
} } } } }
```

and

```
"responses" : {
  "200": {
    "description": "a pet to be returned",
    "schema": {
      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Pet"
} } }
```

I've put this example into a trivial json swagger spec (json) and run the Swagger-Codegen (python, flask) to generate my controllers and model.  Yaml seems to be the preferred internal representation, so when the generator runs it creates a yaml file.

With the former, the response type is "None"

```
responses:
  200:
    description: "a pet to be returned"
```

whereas the latter yields what I think I should be expecting:

```
responses:
  200:
    description: "a pet to be returned"
    schema:
      $ref: "#/components/schemas/Pet"
```

eg, the schema seems to be omitted from the first syntax using `Content`

What does content mean?
What am i missing from the example, why doesn't the `Content` result in a non-None return type and corresponding schema.

Note on the SwaggerCodgen: the generated code matches exactly what the generated yaml says, hence I haven't included any of those details here

Answer (score 5):

The first example is OpenAPI 3.0, the second example is OpenAPI 2.0, hence the difference.

The `content` keyword used in OpenAPI 3.0 is a replacement for `consumes`/`produces` from OpenAPI 2.0. In the context of `responses`, `content` means that the response has a body and specifies the media type (JSON/XML/etc.) and structure of the response body.

OpenAPI 2.0 version:

```yaml
swagger: "2.0"
...
paths:
  /foo:
    get:
      produces:
        - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Pet"
```

OpenAPI 3.0 version:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
...
paths:
  /foo:
    get:
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Pet"
```

The codegen issue is likely caused by any of the fololowing:

- codegen does not support OpenAPI 3.0 yet
- the spec is not valid (e.g. uses a mix of 2.0 and 3.0 keywords)

Comment: Thanks, i totally missed that.   I've upvoted your answer, and will mark it correct once i can verify with the codegen.  removal of the 'produces' in 3.0 seems much more intuitive to me, so I'm trying to do this in 3.0 not 2.0 openapi.  I have converted my swagger spec to 3.0 with swagger2openapi, but am having trouble obtaining/running the codegen in 3.0.  It appears supported in git, but i'm not finding any pre-built jars or docker containers to run.

Comment: I see  https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/io/swagger/swagger-codegen-cli/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/, but it fails and appears to be executing 2.0 (??) `[main] INFO io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser - reading from /input/myspec.openapi3.json
[main] INFO io.swagger.codegen.ignore.CodegenIgnoreProcessor - No .swagger-codegen-ignore file found.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: missing swagger input or config!`

Comment: I suggest you open an issue in the [swagger-codegen repo](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues).

Comment: unfortunately i haven't been able to get back in and verify this, as I do not currently have any active code using the codgen.  I hope to verify it's fixed (sure hope it is years later) - but would also accept someone who is actively looking at this simply confirming that it works with `3.0+`, which as in discussion with @Helen above wasn't available at the time.